# Get all leafs in an adjacency list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph, adjacency-list

Given a structure like the following:

```
graph = {

    # c1 is root node, graph is directed, c1 is source/root node
    'c1': ['c2', 'c3'],
    'c2': ['c4']

}

      c1
      /\
     /  \ 
    c2   c3
   /
  /
c4
```

What would be a general-purpose algorithm to find all the leafs on the graph? My first thought was:

```
# values in the 'from' section, that don't have a 'to' entry
set(itertools.chain(*graph.values())) - set(graph.keys())
# {'c3', 'c4'}
```

Is this the proper way to do it? What would be some other approaches to determine if something is a leaf or not?

Comment: Are these algorithms not readily available with a browser search?  Graph theory is well covered; I would think that "graph algorithm find all leaf nodes" would turn up what you need.

Comment: I believe that `c1` is also a leaf; it's connected to only one other node.  However, perhaps you're working with an implied definition where this doesn't hold.  Are these directed edges, where you're looking for terminal nodes?  Terminals with only one final edge to them?

Comment: @Prune -- yes, 'c1' would be the root node where everything else descends from.

Comment: What is a leaf in a graph?

Comment: @Daniel like the bottom/furthest-out point in a graph, which only has parents and no children.

Comment: @Daniel -- updated question.

Comment: If there is no chance of existing something like `'c3' : []`, then your answer seems right to me.

Comment: A small note, it is better to use `chain.from_iterable(...)` than `chain(*...)`. And `graph.keys()` is a set view already, so `set(graph.keys())` is redundant in this case.

Comment: Looks like your current approach is O(|V|^2), e.g. take a complete graph. If nodes are custom objects, you could store the number of inbound connections or use something like `weakref`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem good idea. Would you want to show how to do that in an answer?

Comment: @kaya3 is `dict_keys` the same as a set, or some variation? `>>> d={'a':'b'}
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['a'])`

Comment: @David542 It is a [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) of the keys of the dictionary, which can be used as if it is a set. Python uses [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) so something doesn't need to be an instance of `set` for it to be usable as a set. A `dict_keys` object supports set operations like `-`, `|`, `&` and `^`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might simplify your piece to make it more efficient:

```
leaves = set()
leaves.update(*graph.values())
leaves -= graph.keys()
```

Comment: could you please explain this approach?

Comment: It is following the same logic as your algorithm but is around 20% faster.